# How do put a header inside the margins?

Tags: header-footer, margins, fancyhdr

I have to create a document that obeys the following guidelines:

> "Margins must be set at a minimum of ¾" (1.87 cm);
>
> Your name must appear outside the set margins of the page, at the top
>   right corner of every page;"

I have also been informed that I should put other things in the left and centre of the header, in addition to my name.

I'd had planned to do this with `fancyhdr`, something like:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

%Set the margins
%I have no idea what headheight=15pt does, but it makes an error go away.
\usepackage[margin=1.87 cm, headheight=15pt]{geometry} 

%Customizing the header
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well
\rhead{Canageek}
\chead{B.Sc (Honours Chemistry)}
\lhead{PIN: 314159}
%End footer

\begin{document}
Scholarship application that will give me lots of money.
\end{document}
```

But this places the header inside the margins, which I think is not what the guidelines are asking for. In specific, the top the the letters are 7 mm from the top of the page, and the bottom of the letters is 1 cm from the top of the page.

Before someone points it out; I am aware that 0.75 inches is not 1.83 cm, someone in the Canadian goverment can't do math.

Comment: What do you need this for? Some conferences, journals, and universities provide class and style files for articles and theses....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When I run your code, an error

```
Package Fancyhdr Warning: \headheight is too small (12.0pt): 
 Make it at least 14.49998pt.
 We now make it that large for the rest of the document.
 This may cause the page layout to be inconsistent, however.
```

is thrown out.

To correct it, make `headheight` somewhat larger as in

```
\usepackage[margin=1.87 cm,headheight=18pt]{geometry}.
```

I have also adjusted the `headsep` to reduce some space above.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

%Set the margins
\usepackage[margin=.75in,showframe,headheight=18pt,headsep=\baselineskip]{geometry}

%Customizing the header
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well
\rhead{Canageek}
\chead{B.Sc (Honours Chemistry)}
\lhead{PIN: 314159}
%End footer

\begin{document}
Scholarship application that will give me lots of money.
\end{document}
```

Here, `showframe` is used just to show the borders.

**Update**

From the comments, it is understood that you want to include head and foot inside text area. This can be done by adding `includehead` and `includefoot` in the options for geometry.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

%Set the margins
\usepackage[margin=.75in,showframe,headheight=15pt,headsep=\baselineskip,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}

%Customizing the header
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancyplain}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well
\rhead{Canageek}
\chead{B.Sc (Honours Chemistry)}
\lhead{PIN: 314159}
%End footer

\begin{document}
Scholarship application that will give me lots of money.
\end{document}
```

[image]

As a side note, if you do not want margin notes you may add `marginparwidth=0pt,marginparsep=0pt,` in to the options of geometry.